# Discussion Board: HTML appearing in reply

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, discussion-board, richhtmlfield

I set up a discussion board a while ago (mid 2015) on our O365 SharePoint to test styling. I cannot see anything different to the default set up except for a custom view. But, when I reply to a post on the discussion board, the HTML tags in the reply are visible unless I edit the source code (which is a pain in the bum and most users will not know or want to know how to do).

Here is a clipped screenshot showing you what I mean:

[image: Screenshot to show HTML displayed in Reply on Discussion Board.]

**Does anyone know why it could be doing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

The Body text had been changed from Rich HTML text field to a Plain text field. Changing this back to Rich HTML fixed the problem.

I'm not entirely sure why, but I suspect it is because the Reply field and Body text are linked in some way. I cannot see if it is possible to make the Reply field plain text as well; I imagine this would also fix the issue in a round-about fashion.